# Pandas Data Frame Average Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, pandas-groupby

I have a large dataset that looks like this:

```
 Year    Month    Day    Hour   Count   Value
 2017      1       1      1       59      0
  ..       ..     ..      ..       ..    ..
 2011      12      29     23      60     12
```

I am trying to use Pandas to generate averages for the Value column for the same month,day,and hour.

I've used this in the past:

```
df = pd.read_csv('pathtofile/values.csv')
df1 = df.groupby([df.Month,df.Day,df.Hour]).mean()
```

however the new df1 will not average the Value column, it does however provide an average for the Count and Year column (which are of no interest to me). I'm thinking that this has something to do with the data in the Value column as most of the values are zero. I've tried replacing all the zero values with null values however to no avail.

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: df1= df.groupby(['Month','Day','Hour'])  then do  df1['Value'].mean()

Comment: is the value column actually numeric? check with `df.info()`

Comment: @PaulH This appears to be the issue. It is a "Object" type, not and Int64 like the rest of the values. The answer I've accepted as correct below converts it to a float where it is successfully able to provide the average values. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
df['Value'] = df['Value'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
df.groupby(['Month', 'Day', 'Hour']).agg({'Value': np.mean})
```

Comment: Thank you! The issue was that the Value field was imported as an Object. Converting it to a numeric float allowed me to calculate the average.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to have the code run as expected.

I made my own test file called 'values.txt' and looked like

```
Year,Month,Day,Hour,Count,Value
2017,1,1,1,59,0
2016,1,1,1,45,12
2014,2,3,4,34,43
2013,1,1,1,12,56
```

Then I entered

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('values.txt')
>>> df
   Year  Month  Day  Hour  Count  Value
0  2017      1    1     1     59      0
1  2016      1    1     1     45     12
2  2014      2    3     4     34     43
3  2013      1    1     1     12     56
```

And finally I reached the result I believe you want through

```
>>> df1 = df.groupby(['Month', 'Day', 'Hour'])
>>> df1['Value'].mean()
Month  Day  Hour
1      1    1       22.666667
2      3    4       43.000000
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

I think I agree with Paul H, you should check if the column is a string. As I also have sucess with:

```
>>> df1 = df.groupby(['Month', 'Day', 'Hour']).mean()
>>> df1
                       Year      Count      Value
Month Day Hour                                   
1     1   1     2015.333333  38.666667  22.666667
2     3   4     2014.000000  34.000000  43.000000
```

Can you edit in the output when you print df1?

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get it to work by converting the data type to a float as Paul H suggested. I'd upvote you but don't have enough reputation. Thanks for all the work!

Comment: No worries happy to help. Need some way to pass the time when I'm snowed in ;)